# Are mvrnorm() in MASS R package and rmvn() in mgcv R package equivalent?

Tags: r, simulation, multivariate-normal-distribution, mgcv, numerics

I am carrying out posterior simulation with GAMs/SCAMs and was wondering if/how the `rmvn()` function differs in any way from the `mvrnorm()` function in `mgcv`.

I ask because if there is already a function to perform MVN simulation in the MASS package, then why was `rmvn()` created for `mgcv`? This leads me to believe either:

(1) there is a fundamental difference between these two functions; or,

(2) there is no difference, and `rmvn()` was created simply for convenience (i.e., not having to install/load another package).

I ask this because replacing `mvrnorm()` used here:

[Can I use bootstrapping to estimate the uncertainty in a maximum value of a GAM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190348/can-i-use-bootstrapping-to-estimate-the-uncertainty-in-a-maximum-value-of-a-gam/191489#191489)

with `rmvn()` results in an error that "mu dimensions are wrong" when applied to SCAM objects:

see: [Posterior Simulation of a shape constrained additive model (SCAM)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317837/posterior-simulation-of-a-shape-constrained-additive-model-scam).

This behaviour leads me to believe that there is a difference between `mvrnorm()` and `rmvn()`. Or, there may be a critical bug that Simon Wood (the creator and maintainer of `mgcv`) should be informed on.

Is there really a difference that should lead me to using one function over the other? My intuition says no, but I would like to be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MASS::mvrnorm`  and `mgcv::rmvn`  do the same thing, simulates from a multivariate normal distribution. So why did the `mgcv` author replicate functionality already in MASS? We don't know, you should rather ask @Simon Wood!

But, the two functions use different methods: `MASS::mvrnorm` uses the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix, while `mgcv::rmvn` calls `mgcv::mroot`, a function which by default uses the Choleski decomposition. That might be faster, but potentially less accurate (according to the authors of `MASS`).